What is the alternative to Whis: 'range'?
Earlier I used whis = 'range' like this:
box = plt.boxplot(data, whis = 'range', widths = 0.15, patch_artist = True, 
                  showfliers = False)

In the newer matplotlib versions, whis is a float. What should be the new whis value as an alternative to 'range'?

One way to do this is to use a high value (such as a large float) to approximate including the entire range of the data. Here is an example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=100),
    'B': np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=2, size=100),
    'C': np.random.normal(loc=-3, scale=1.5, size=100)
})

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
box = plt.boxplot(data.values, whis=1000000, widths=0.15, patch_artist=True, showfliers=False)

colors = ['pink', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen']
for patch, color in zip(box['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

plt.xticks([1, 2, 3], data.columns)
plt.title('Boxplot with Updated whis Parameter')
plt.xlabel('Columns')
plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.show()



"The only way ...", make that "One way ..." ;). You can use (0,100).

TL;DR
As of plt.boxplot 3.3.4, use whis=(0, 100) instead of whis='range' to set whiskers to min and max of the data.

From the docs for plt.boxplot 2.2.4, section whis:

whis can be the string 'range' to force the whiskers to the min and max of the data.

This use has been deprecated since plt.boxplot 3.3.4. As of this version, whis can be either a float or a pair of floats: (float, float) (i.e. a tuple). From section whis:

If a pair of floats, they indicate the percentiles at which to draw the whiskers (e.g., (5, 95)). In particular, setting this to (0, 100) results in whiskers covering the whole range of the data. "range" is a deprecated synonym for (0, 100). [bold added]

This still works the same in 3.9, current stable version.
Example
Left is with default whiskers, right with (0, 100).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.concatenate([
    np.repeat(np.arange(10), 2),
    np.repeat(np.arange(10, 20), 3),
    np.repeat(np.arange(20, 26), 15)
])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))

for ax, whis, title in zip(axes, 
                           [None, (0, 100)], 
                           ['Default Whiskers (1.5 IQR)', 
                            'Whiskers Min / Max ("range")']
                           ):
    ax.boxplot(data, whis=whis)
    ax.set_title(title)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

Result:


Thank you, does autorange=True work?

Well, that depends on your data. From the docs, section autorange: "When True and the data are distributed such that the 25th and 75th percentiles are equal, whis is set to (0, 100) such that the whisker ends are at the minimum and maximum of the data." So, only if Q1 == Q3, which is not True for the example above. But suppose you would use data = np.concatenate([np.repeat(np.arange(10), 5), np.repeat(np.arange(10, 20), 10), np.repeat(np.arange(20, 30), 5)]), and set autorange=True. Then yes.
